# How does Keras define "accuracy" and "loss"?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras

I can't find how Keras defines "accuracy" and "loss". I know I can specify different metrics (e.g. mse, cross entropy) but Keras prints out a standard "accuracy". How is that defined? Likewise for loss; I know I can specify different types of regularization; are those in the loss?

Ideally, I'd like to print out the equation used to define it; if not, I'll settle for an answer here.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Have a look at [`metrics.py`](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/c2e36f369b411ad1d0a40ac096fe35f73b9dffd3/keras/metrics.py), there you can find definition of all available metrics including different types of accuracy. Accuracy is not printed unless you add it to the list of desired metrics when you compile your model.

Regularizers are by definition added to the loss. For example, see [`add_loss`](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/f573a86b42e49754386e536358e08e861d40d24c/keras/engine/topology.py#L417) method of the `Layer`class.

**Update**

The type of `accuracy` is determined based on the objective function, see [`training.py`](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/d8b226f26b35348d934edb1213061993e7e5a1fa/keras/engine/training.py#L651). The default choice is [`categorical_accuracy`](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/c2e36f369b411ad1d0a40ac096fe35f73b9dffd3/keras/metrics.py#L13). Other types like `binary_accuracy` and `sparse_categorical_accuracy` are selected when the objective function is either binary or sparse.

Comment: If I add to the metrics `'accuracy'`, which metric is that? There are several in `metrics.py` that have the word "accuracy" in them?

Comment: Thanks.  But what is selected if the objective function is neither, but is `mse`? What does `accuracy` mean in that context?

Comment: In such case `categorical_accuracy` is selected and it means according to the documentation "Calculates the mean accuracy rate across all predictions for multiclass classification problems". If your problem is not classification, then it does not make much sense to include accuracy. @SRobertJames

Comment: @SergiiGryshkevych I clicked the link for `categorical_accuracy`. Seems `categorical_accuracy` is no longer a scalar. It's an array now if I'm not mistaken. [`categorical_accuracy`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/metrics.py#L1905)

Answer (score 1):

Since [Sergii's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41534323/19123103), Keras library has been cleaned up quite a bit and the source code is pretty readable nowadays. The metrics are defined in `tensorflow.keras.metrics` (whose documentation can be found [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics)) and the losses are defined in `tensorflow.keras.losses` ([docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses)). There's a bit of overlap with the metrics module but that's expected given a particular loss function can also be tracked as a metric.

Also, if we inspect the [source code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/428ed9f03a0a0b2edc22d4ce29001857f617227c/keras/engine/compile_utils.py#L665), unless the metric is accuracy, `get()` method is called on the `metrics` module to get the particular metric function, i.e. `tf.keras.metrics.get('binary_accuracy')`. On the other hand, the `get()` method is always called to [fetch](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/428ed9f03a0a0b2edc22d4ce29001857f617227c/keras/engine/compile_utils.py#L365) the particular loss function.

Also, the type of accuracy [is chosen](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/428ed9f03a0a0b2edc22d4ce29001857f617227c/keras/engine/compile_utils.py#L677-L683) depending on the the target type (`binary_accuracy`, `categorical_accuracy` etc.).

All metrics/losses can be printed calling `dir()` on the modules.

```py
metrics_list = [m for m in dir(tf.keras.metrics) if not m.startswith('_')]

losses_list = [m for m in dir(tf.keras.losses) if not m.startswith('_')]
```