# Keras unsymmetrical data Diabetic Retinopathy Detection

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, theano-cuda

I'm trying to make a predictive model for [Diabetic Retinopathy Detection](https://www.kaggle.com/c/diabetic-retinopathy-detection). The competition's trainig dataset includes hy-res images are unsymmetricaly divided in 5 classes: Normal-25807 images-73.48%; Mild-2442 images-6.96%; Moderate-5291 images-15.07%; Severe-873 images-2.48% and Proliferative-708 images - 2.01%.
For this purpose I use Keras framework with Theano backend (for CUDA comutations).

For image augmentation I used the ImageDataGenerator (the code is below). I've resized images to 299x299 and divided them into 5 folders accordingly their classes:

```
train_datagen=ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, rotation_range=40, zoom_range=0.2, horizontal_flip=True, fill_mode="constant", zca_whitening=True)
train_generator=train_datagen.flow_from_directory('data/~huge_data/preprocessed_imgs/', target_size=(299, 299), batch_size=32, class_mode='categorical')
```

At first, just for testing, I desided to use a simple convolutional model:

```
model=Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(32,3,3, input_shape=(3, 299, 299), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(5, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
              optimizer='rmsprop', 
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

In fitting Image generator, I pointed the class_weights in order to fix the asymmetry of data: class_weight ={0: 25807., 1:2442., 2:5291., 3:873., 4:708.};

```
model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                   samples_per_epoch=2000,
                   nb_epoch=50, 
                    verbose=2, 
                   callbacks=callbacks_list,
                   class_weight ={0: 25807., 1:2442., 2:5291., 3:873., 4:708.})
```

[My folders with images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVQr9.png)

Problems:

1. The model outputs with high loss and high accuracy. Why?

Epoch 1/50
110s - loss: 5147.2669 - acc: 0.7366

Epoch 2/50
105s - loss: 5052.3844 - acc: 0.7302

Epoch 3/50
105s - loss: 5042.0261 - acc: 0.7421

Epoch 4/50
105s - loss: 4986.3544 - acc: 0.7361

Epoch 5/50
105s - loss: 4999.4177 - acc: 0.7361

2. Every image model predict as '0' class:

datagen_2=ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

```
val_generator=datagen_2.flow_from_directory('data/color_validation_images/',
                                         target_size=(299,299),
                                         batch_size=100,
                                           class_mode='categorical')

y_predict=model.predict_generator(val_generator,
                       val_samples=82)


[np.argmax(i) for i in y_predict]
```

the output of it is:

```
0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0
```

without argmax(partly)

```
array([  9.47651565e-01,   7.30426749e-03,   4.40788604e-02,
          6.25302084e-04,   3.39932943e-04], dtype=float32),
 array([  9.51994598e-01,   6.50278665e-03,   4.07058187e-02,
          5.17037639e-04,   2.79774162e-04], dtype=float32),
 array([  9.49448049e-01,   6.50656316e-03,   4.32702228e-02,
          5.20388770e-04,   2.54814397e-04], dtype=float32),
 array([  9.47873473e-01,   7.13181263e-03,   4.40776311e-02,
          6.00705389e-04,   3.16353660e-04], dtype=float32),
 array([  9.53514516e-01,   6.13699574e-03,   3.96034382e-02,
          4.82603034e-04,   2.62484333e-04], dtype=float32),
....
```

If I've tried to use class_weight ='auto'. In this case, model showed 'predictable' output:

Epoch 1/50
107s - loss: 0.9036 - acc: 0.7381

Epoch 2/50
104s - loss: 0.9333 - acc: 0.7321

Epoch 3/50
105s - loss: 0.8865 - acc: 0.7351

Epoch 4/50
106s - loss: 0.8978 - acc: 0.7351

Epoch 5/50
105s - loss: 0.9158 - acc: 0.7302

But, it still doesn't work:

```
severe_DR=plt.imread('data/~huge_data/preprocessed_imgs/3_Severe/99_left.jpeg')
mild_DR=plt.imread('data/~huge_data/preprocessed_imgs/1_Mild/15_left.jpeg')
moderate_DR=plt.imread('data/~huge_data/preprocessed_imgs/2_Moderate/78_right.jpeg')

model.predict(mild_DR.reshape((1,)+x[1].shape))
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]], dtype=float32)

model.predict(severe_DR.reshape((1,)+x[1].shape))
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]], dtype=float32)

model.predict(moderate_DR.reshape((1,)+x[1].shape))
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]], dtype=float32)
```

What I've done wrong?

---

After answer of Sergii Gryshkevych, I fixed my model: I've changed class_weight to {0:1, 1:10.57, 2:4.88, 3:29, 4:35} (I divided images in each classes to maximum images (in first class)). Next, I changed metrics to categorical_accuracy. And I inctreased the number of layers in model (like [here](https://deepsense.io/diagnosing-diabetic-retinopathy-with-deep-learning/)). 
So, the output after 5 epochs is:

Epoch 1/5
500/500 [==============================] - 52s - loss: 5.6944 - categorical_accuracy: 0.1840
Epoch 2/5
500/500 [==============================] - 52s - loss: 6.7357 - categorical_accuracy: 0.2040
Epoch 3/5
500/500 [==============================] - 52s - loss: 6.7373 - categorical_accuracy: 0.0800
Epoch 4/5
500/500 [==============================] - 52s - loss: 6.0311 - categorical_accuracy: 0.0180
Epoch 5/5
500/500 [==============================] - 51s - loss: 4.9924 - categorical_accuracy: 0.0560

Is it correct?

Is there any way to make assign a quadratic weighted kappa as metrics in keras?

Answer (score 3):

"High" accuracy around 73-74% comes from the fact that all images are classified as `0` class. Your data set is imbalanced, since the majority class accounts for 73% of samples. So accuracy does not say much in this case, you need to use other metrics derived from confusion matrix like precision, recall, F1 score, etc.

Multiclass log loss function punishes wrong predictions extremely. Your predictions are almost zero for all classes except the `0`, so there is nothing surprising in such high loss values.

To sum up, you are facing classic Class Imbalance Problem. Two most common ways to mitigate it are

1. Adjust class weights. Make minority classes "more important", so learning algorithm does not ignore them. You can provide your custom class weights as an argument to the `fit` method:

> `class_weight`: dictionary mapping classes to a weight value, used for scaling the loss function (during training only).

2. Oversampling/Undersampling. Simply oversample examples of minority classes to make your data set balanced, or combine it with undersampling, when some randomly selected examples of the majority class are dropped at the beginning of each learning epoch.

The Class Imbalance problem is nothing new, so there is plenty of reading on this topic like [this](http://www.chioka.in/class-imbalance-problem/) and [this](http://machinelearningmastery.com/tactics-to-combat-imbalanced-classes-in-your-machine-learning-dataset/) introductory posts.

Comment: Sergii, thank you for your answer! I've changed my model, but it still does something wrong. I've write the output in my answer below the -------------

Comment: It is hard to draw any conclusions after only 5 epochs. Loss values look much more reasonable now. Let it train more. By the way, `categorical_accuracy` is the same as just `accuracy` in this case. See this [question about how does Keras define accuracy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41531695/how-does-keras-define-accuracy-and-loss/41534323) @MaxTitkov