# Meaning of acc info output in Keras training procedure

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to create a seq2seq network having as backbone a network architecture defined in this [machinelearningmastery](https://machinelearningmastery.com/develop-encoder-decoder-model-sequence-sequence-prediction-keras/) blog. Basically the original example uses input 6D and output 3D sequences while mine uses 32D and output 32D.

More precisely the original model uses random integer (ranging from 1 to 50 in value range) sequence of 6 integers. My model uses 32D values (ranging 0-255 in value).

As I was watching the model trainig I noticed that there two criteria for judging converging: `loss` and metrics (usually accuracy). Typical info would be something like:

```
99776/100000 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0223 - acc: 0.9967
99904/100000 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0223 - acc: 0.9967
100000/100000 [==============================] - 40s 400us/step - loss: 0.0223 - acc: 0.9967
```

Ok in the (simple) blog example I can see the `loss` going down while the `acc` going up to 1 simultaneously. Though in my case (which is a harder problem to solve) I can see the `loss` going down and the accuracy going up to value `1.0` quite rapidly comparing to the `loss`. Some observation I have made checking on these info message:

- After some iterations I can have an accuracy of `1.0` and my `loss`
  would be still definitely above the zero threshold (e.g. `0.0222`). I mean I don't get `loss` in the magnitude order of `1e-5` for example or something.
- At the start of each epoch there seem to be a loss and definitely accuracy gap. I found a good explanation about this in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48280873/what-is-the-difference-between-loss-function-and-metric-in-keras/48281534). In a summary, it says that during an epoch the `loss` and `acc` being displayed are the mean values over all batches, while at every new epoch this is initialized to the actual current value.
- Even when the `acc` is fixed to `1.0` and I am performance on my training data I do not get such high results to justify this high accuracy.

So, my question is what is this accuracy showing anyway? I know that it's [meant only for the programmer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48280873/what-is-the-difference-between-loss-function-and-metric-in-keras/48281534) (me that is) and it's not used by the model itself (unlike `loss` which is used) but how is it calculated or what does it represent anyway? In my case I have sequences of 32D values ranging from 0-255 so each sequence is represented as an array of size `(32, 257)`. So, accuracy 0.99 means 99 out of 100 sequences match? Is that so?

Comment: Answer here may be useful (disclaimer: mine), at least for a high-level understanding: [Loss & accuracy - Are these reasonable learning curves?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47817424/loss-accuracy-are-these-reasonable-learning-curves/47819022#47819022)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, my question is what is this accuracy showing anyway?

As explained [in this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41531695/how-does-keras-define-accuracy-and-loss), the actual accuracy metric that keras chooses depends on the loss that you have chosen. 
I would have guessed that in your case, it defaults to [categorical_accuracy](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/metrics.py#L30):

```
def categorical_accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.cast(K.equal(K.argmax(y_true, axis=-1),
                          K.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1)), K.floatx())
```

which would mean that it compares whether the maximum value in y_true and y_pred occur on the same position. That, of course, would not be very meaningful for you.